# How to change the Signed in Phone Number in Firebase Authentication for Android?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using [Android Firebase Auth Ui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md) for providing Phone Number based sign in option in an android app. I am trying to provide an additional option to signed in users to switch their signed in phone number to another number keeping the same user account.

But as per [Firebase Docs for Phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) there are no options to change the signed in number.

There are options for linking different auth providers like email, google or Facebook login etc to same account. But there is no way mentioned about how to change the phone number or email id keeping the same user id.

Is there a workaround or method by which we can achieve this?

Comment: you can transfer user info to new number by USER token or id

Comment: Can you me more specific about how to do that? Or point me to a link where such a method is explained.

Comment: i am just guessing, when user switch number just create another entry in your firebase db with different userid but copy old data to new user id. then delete old entry

Comment: That is a great workaround possible. But it won't be suitable to my use case. I have many other db tables where user id is recorded.

Comment: make cloud function so change user id in all other table. I did not find any other solution now

Comment: is user number is used anywhere except authenticating?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An API exists for updating the phone number of a current user: [`FirebaseUser#updatePhoneNumber(PhoneAuthCredential credential)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential))

Comment: You must have to give an short example.

Comment: @PratikButani i also dont understand why the doc doesnt reflect how the code looks or works. its so abstract i dont understand it either.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this challenge to update user phone number and when I go on documentation I got something by using I have done this task.

you can go for documentation by click [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential))

Now the method you can use : - for java android project.

```
PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential( "+91-98298XXXX2", "OTP_CODE" );
// Update Mobile Number...
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().updatePhoneNumber(phoneAuthCredential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener <Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task <Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Update Successfully
            } else {
                // Failed
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) // Phone number to verify
            .setTimeout(100L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
            .setActivity(activity) // Activity (for callback binding)
            .setCallbacks(returnCallBack()) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .build()

 PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

private fun returnCallBack() = object : PhoneAuthProvider
    .OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()?.updatePhoneNumber(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.e("phone",  e.toString())

        }

        override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            //You need this to pass as a parameter for the update method call.
            vericationSent = verificationId
        }
    }   

 fun confirmChange(code: String, context: Context?) {
        if(code.contains(Regex(onlyNumber))) {
            Log.d("codeSent" , "Right code : $code")

            FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()
                ?.updatePhoneNumber(PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(vericationSent, code))
                ?.addOnCompleteListener {task ->
                    //it worked if you reach here.

                }?.addOnFailureListener {
                    //Show the error to user
                    }
                }

            vericationSent = EMPTY
        } else {
            Log.d("codeSent" , "wrong code : $code")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi TheSeeKer. Thanks for your answer. Usually answers with an explanation are more welcomed there. Would you like to add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: Hi MaxV, Make this call  "PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)" using the new phone number ( while building options object) from you old phone device where you have you app (with Firebase Auth). Then once you receive the code from the device you want to start using, take this code use it with the verificationId you receive from onCodeSent callback to make this following call   "FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()
                ?.updatePhoneNumber(PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(vericationSent, code))". That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//Send otp to phone number

String verificationId;
private void startLoginFirebase(){
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance(firebaseAuth).verifyPhoneNumber(phone, 90L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, PhoneAuthActivity.this, new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
            updatePhoneNum();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(@NonNull String s) {
            super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            processFurther(e.getLocalizedMessage().toString(), 0);
        }
    });
}


//Verify Otp

private void updatePhoneNum(){
    PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otp);
    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().updatePhoneNumber(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently - according to the project maintainers - FirebaseUI-Android [doesn't support this feature](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1701), and it looks like they have no plans of doing it any time soon :(