# Changing phone number for Firebase Phone Auth creates a new user UID?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, uid

I used Firebase Phone Auth generated UID as my user's unique id for the database. If the user wants to change their phone number later on, would it change the generated UID as well?

Comment: If you want to update the phone number of an existing user, use the `updatePhoneNumber` API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601591/how-to-change-the-signed-in-phone-number-in-firebase-authentication-for-android, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389952/209103

Comment: Thank you! But question is not "how to update phone number", but would updating the phone number affect the previously generated Firebase uid and create a new one? I am sorry if I was confusing

Comment: You're updating the phone number of an existing account, so it will keep its existing UID.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! It really saves me a lot of time!